# My brand new LCD screen doesn't display anything, even though there is no code errors?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I have a LCD screen, and I wanted to use it with a Simon Says game that I am making. I tried the tutorial on the Arduino website, but it doesn't work. Then I tried another tutorial on [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-11-lcd-displays-1/). On this one, the LCD screen seemed brighter which is good, but it also doesn't work.

**What it is supposed to look like:**
[image]

**My code:**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  lcd.print("Test!");
  delay(500);
  lcd.clear();
  delay(500);
}
```

I have verified that the wiring is correct on the official version and the Adafruit version, and my screen is brand new from the kit, so what is wrong?

**Edit 1:**

Let me define "doesn't work." I can turn the potentiometer, but nothing changes. I can't even see white rectangles or even a single pixel on the display. It is blank. Absolutely nothing to see other than the blacklight, which does work.

**Edit 2:**

Turns out that the diagram was wrong. Needed to move the potentiometer 1 pin to the right, now it works!

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Can you adjust the contrast to see dark blocks? Can you see anything else beside the blocks?

Comment: I can't even see any dark blocks. _Nothing_ works except for the blacklight. If I were to turn the potentiometer, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the diagram was wrong. Needed to move the potentiometer 1 pin to the right, now it works!